# Assertion Failure in UICollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect on ios7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, xcode5, uicollectionviewlayout

Assertion Failure in `UICollectionViewData` `validateLayoutInRect` on iOS7.

I am trying to delete all `UICollectionView` items, one by one, using a `for` loop; I posted my code below. I delete the `UICollectionView` items using `deleteItemsAtIndexPaths`. It's **working perfectly on iOS6**, but **crashes in iOS7** with this exception:

> Assertion Failure in UICollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect

I delete the object from `collectionArray` then `self.collectionView`, one by one, using `indexPath`. When I delete the 4th object its raises `Assertion failure` on iOS7. Here I am using `performBatchUpdates`.

Please help me get the proper result in iOS7. Share proper code.
Thanks in advance.

```
try  {    
    for (int i=count-1; i>=0; i--)  {  
        [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^(void){  
            [collectionArray removeObjectAtIndex:i]; // First delete the item from you model   
            [self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]]];  
        } completion:nil];
        [self.collectionView reloadData];
    }
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
}
@finally {
}
```

Comment: looks like you have the same problem as mentioned in:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18189311/bad-access-on-uicollectionview-setcollectionviewlayoutanimated and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339030/uicollectionview-assertion-error-on-stale-data

Comment: @IvanLisovyi The first one is a crash when sending a message to an object whereas this here is an exception thrown by a failing assertion. No relationship whatsoever.  The 2nd one may be related but I cannot say for sure as it's not said here what exception is thrown exactly.

Answer (score 24):

I actually got this crash one time not because I was returning zero for a number of sections or items in a section but because I was reusing a flow layout like this for more than 1 collection view:

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
[flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
Collection1 = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 50.0f) collectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
[Collection1 setDataSource:self];
[Collection1 setDelegate:self];
[self.view addSubview:Collection1];

Collection2 = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, self.view.frame.size.height) collectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
Collection2.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Instead if I create a new flow layout for each UICollectionView I avoid this crash. Hopefully that might help someone

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
[flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
Collection1 = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 50.0f) collectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
[Collection1 setDataSource:self];
[Collection1 setDelegate:self];
[self.view Collection1];

UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayoutVert = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
[flowLayoutVert setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];
Collection2 = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, self.view.frame.size.height) collectionViewLayout:flowLayoutVert];
```

Comment: I am doing the same thing but to no avail.

Comment: A big help. Save my tons of time.

Comment: Makes me glad I write some of these things down when it actually helps someone.

Answer (score 20):

in iOS 10 you must disable the prefetchingEnabled:

```
// Swift
if #available(iOS 10, *) { 
    collectionView.prefetchingEnabled = false 
}

//Obj C
if ([self.collectionView respondsToSelector:@selector(setPrefetchingEnabled:)]) {
    self.collectionView.prefetchingEnabled = false;
}
```

Comment: You sir are a life saver. Thanks. It really fixed my problem as I am using a custom FlowLayout class.

Comment: kisses and hags

Comment: Yes _iUser_ You can do that or By opening Attribute-inspector pan in storyboard for that particular _collection-view_  by uncheck the prefetch property.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you probably want to do this:

```
[self.CollectionView performBatchUpdates:^(void) {
  for (int i = count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    [collectionArray removeObjectAtIndex:i]; // First delete the item from you model
    [self.CollectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]]];
  }
} completion:nil];
```

So that all the updates are performed together. Otherwise you will end up trying to perform several lots of batch updates on top of each other.

Answer (score 4):

[image: layout lifecycle]

You should implement **invalidateLayout** in your `layoutClass` and remove all kinds of `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` items in your config.

```
- (void)invalidateLayout{
  [super invalidateLayout];
  [self.itemsAttributes removeAllObjects];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try to call `[yourCollectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];`

Answer (score 2):

You should implement invalidateLayout in your layout class and remove all kinds of `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` items in your config.

```
- (void)invalidateLayout{
  [super invalidateLayout];
  [self.itemsAttributes removeAllObjects];
}
```

---

For a better way to implement `invalidateLayoutWithContext`, see more about  `UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext`.

From [Apple Developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscollectionviewlayout/1533282-invalidatelayoutwithcontext):

> When implementing a custom layout, you can override this method and use 
>   it to process information provided by a custom invalidation context. 
>   You are not required to provide a custom invalidation context but might 
>   do so if you are able to provide additional properties that can help 
>   optimize layout updates. If you override this method, you must call 
>   super at some point in your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

In my case following delegate was missing:

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    [collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: This causes a stack overflow.